# escaping the whole array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to escape the whole array using a escaping function so far what i have done is i can escape a single value which comes through post but its really time consuming process to escape every single input i have tried to create a function for escaping the whole array as i am using codeigniter so most of the work done with arrays.

Here is the function in controller for more explanation !.

```
$data=array(
      'fname'=>$this->input->post('fname'),
      'lname'=>$this->input->post('lname'),
      'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
      'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
      'birth_year'=>$this->input->post('birth_year'),
      'mobile_phone'=>$this->input->post('mobile_phone'),
      'bio_data'=>$this->input->post('bio_data'),
      'gender'=>$this->input->post('gender'),
      );
      $data1=$this->adminmodel->escape_array($data);
```

Here is the function which escape single post value.

```
function escape($input){
        if(!empty($input)){
            $input = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
        }
        return $input;
    }
```

And here is function for escaping whole array but its not working probably i am doing some thing wrong any help will be really helpfull .

```
function escape_array($array){
        if(!empty($array)){
         for($i=0; $i<sizeof($array); $i++)
         {  
            $array = mysql_real_escape_string($array[$i]);
         }
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

Comment: you mean like this? array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',$array);

Comment: what err u getting or what ouput u getting, please share.....

Comment: change the database driver.... `mysql_*` is about to get removed.

Comment: i am getting this error when i pass the whole array Undefined offset: 0

Comment: no, no need for that extra function, just use the active record. that should automatically escape inputs

Comment: Ghost but i waana create my own and i can use it in structure php as well it will be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the escaped string in $array, instead you need to assign it to and array variable. Below is updated code for you:

```
function escape_array($array){
        $posts = array();
        if(!empty($array)){
         foreach($array as $key => $value)
         {  
            $posts[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
         }
        }
        return $posts;
    }
```

I updated the code, to work for associative array. I am assuming you being passing single dimensional array to escape_array function.

Comment: i think problem is with associative array because the loop works and it say undefined offset 0 : 1 2 3 and so on according to array length

Comment: If its associative array you need to use foreach instead of for loop and also assign the escaped value to array with index as key of associative array.

Comment: a little help will be appreciated